# bottle.py: sending data via javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, bottle

Basically, I want to have an interactive button on my website, that, when clicked, sends some data to the server in order to be checked and display the response (without form sending / page reload).

I thought it would be something like:

```
function checkData()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var conf = document.getElementById('my_text_area').value;

    req.open("GET", 'check_data', true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        var pre = document.getElementById('check_data_out');
        pre.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }

    req.send(conf);
    return false;
}
```

And on the server side:

```
@get('/check_data')
def check_data():
    # Process the content and answer something...
    content = str(request.is_ajax) + ' - ' + str(request.GET) + ' - ' + str(request.POST)
    return content
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Either it is not the right way to send data via javascript or not the right way to access it in bottle.py.

Showing me how it works is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use javascript library such as dojo and jquery? Otherwise, you  need extra effort to overcome the difference of AJAX among different browsers.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Use Chrome dev tools to inspect the request/response.

Comment: sorry, this question/issue is now too old and I cannot remember the details about it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo for client side logic.

```
var button = dojo.byId('button_id'); // button_id refers to the id of the button you want to click

dojo.connect(button,'onclick',dojo.xhrGet({
   url: '/check_data',
   handleAs : 'text',
   load : function(response){
       dojo.byId('button_id').innerHTML = response; 
   }
}));
```